# ruby on rails - how to take only take one row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Restaurant Load (1.5ms)  SELECT * FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN
"restaurant_branches" ON "restaurant_branches"."restaurant_id" =
"restaurants"."restaurant_id"
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| resta... | res_... | res_... | crea... | updat... | user_id | resta... | addr...
| addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | numb... | numb... | email |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 28       | 405 ...
|         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60666   | USA     |         |         |       |
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 29       | 111 ...
|         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60661   | USA     |         |         |       |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

As you can see, I have two records for record 27. This is from a joined
table between `restaurants` and `restaurant_branches`. How would I approach
this in a view so that when I select a record on my `index.html.erb` file
when it gets routed to the `show.html.erb` file it'll only take one row of
that record and only show me one branch instead of 2?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which Rails query are you using for getting the output?

Answer (score 2):

The two records are different, so keep them separate and list both. It's difficult to say which fields are different from the question.  Based on the query, I'm assuming they are `restaurant_branches` fields that are different.

If it's the restaurants that you want to show/edit then use just `Restaurant.all` however you want to limit.  If however you want to edit the `restaurant_branches` then introduce a `RestaurantBranchesController` and have a link for the branches separate.

Something like (in `erb`):

```
<%= restaurant.id %>
<% restaurant.restaurant_branches.each do |rb| %>
  <%= link_to 'Some branch', rb %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Then the `link_to(rb)` should link you to `RestaurantBranchesController#show` action for the particular `restaurant_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

**Collection**

Further to what `@vee` was suggesting, it seems to me that you're calling a `collection` of data from ActiveRecord. A *collection* basically means you're going to receive a multitude of objects back, rather than just one record

I'd imagine you have your models set up as follows:

```
#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :branches, class_name: "RestaurantBranch"
end

#app/models/restaurant_branch.rb
Class RestaurantBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@restaurant = Restaurant.find params[:id]
@restaurant.branches #-> returns the collection
```

--

**Limit**

The way to fix this will depend on what you're trying to show.

Typically, you can use something like [`limit`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) to retrieve a single record, like so:

```
@restaurant.branches.limit(1)
```

Like most things in life, this will be much simpler to resolve if you define what you want to limit the results for - what's the purpose?